# Regex for finding comma between words

Tags: regex, grep

What's the regular expression for finding all instances of a comma, without a trailing space, between words? e.g. "someword,otherword"?

I'm using this pattern in Eclipse's search tool:

```
([^,\n\s']),([^,\n\s\)\]'])
```

which works perfectly, but when I use this same pattern with grep like:

```
grep -nHIirE -- ([^,\n\s']),([^,\n\s\)\]'])
```

it finds nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _What's the regular expression for finding all instances of a comma, without a trailing space_ = `\S,\S` or `(?<!\s),(?!\s)`

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries `\b`:

```
echo "abc,def ghi, jkl" | grep '\b,\b'
```

*(find the first comma, but not the second)*

Answer (score 0):

Passing `([^,\n\s']),([^,\n\s\)\]'])` to grep is a string literal search, you need to put it in single or double quotes to make it a regex search `"([^,\n\s']),([^,\n\s\)\]'])"`

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` this pattern should work:

```
grep -nHIir -- "[^,'[:space:]],[^],)[:space:]']"
```

- Use `[:space:]` to match any whitespace including newlines
- **Importantly** don't escape `]` inside a negated character class. Just place it at first position.
- Avoid unnecessary grouping
- You don't even need extended regex flavor for this